# C program: Binary not found message and project folder empty although i build my project

Tags: c, eclipse

I try to create simplw `Hello World` C program.
I install `GCC` which is locate under `C:\MinGW` and download `Eclipse`.
I start `Eclipse`, `File --> New ---> C Project`:

Under `Project name` choose `HelloWorld`.

Under `Project type` choose `Hello World ANSI C Project`

Under `Toolchains` i have 3 options: `Cross GCC`, `Microsoft Visual C++` amd `MinGw GCC` so i choose `MinGw GCC`. and hit `Finish`.

Now this is the code that generated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Under `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` i have red lines that says `Unresolved inclusion: <stdio.h>` and `Unresolved inclusion: <stdlib.h>`

So under my project `Properties` --> `C\C++ General` --> `Paths and symbols` in `Includes` tab i have 2 Languages: `Assembly` and `GNU C`. so i choose `GNU C` and in the right side click the `Add` button and under Directory past the path `C:\MinGW\include`.
Now after that all the red lines disappears.
So now i try to run my project so first i build it under `Project` --> `Build all` and see in the `Console` panel in the button of `Eclipse` the message that `Build Finished` and when i try to run my project and Click on Run button i received error that `Launch failed: Binary not found`
I can see that inside my project folder in the Debug folder i only have `src` folder which is empty and that's it.
What i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to add the MingW directory to your windows system path variable.
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;

Comment: bin dir added, msys folder not exist under C:\MinGW